# node keeps executing deleted code after resetting the server?

Tags: json, node.js, express

My  node.js app had this function declared:

```
//deletes a user and its related files.
function deleteUser(userToDelete)
{
  if (userToDelete == null || userToDelete == {})
  {
    return { success: false, message: 'error deleting user 1.'};
}

{
    return { success: false, message: 'error deleting user 2.'};
}
  // delete the entry from the database
  User.findOneAndRemove({ email: userToDelete}, function(err, filesList) {
    if (err)
    {

      return { success: false, message: 'error deleting user.3'};
    }
  });
  //delete related files

  UserFile.remove({owner:userToDelete}, function(err,filesList){
    if (err)
    {
      return { success: false, message: 'user deleted. Error deleting related files.'};
    }
      return { success: true, message: 'user deleted.'};
  });


};
```

I noticed that this part shouldn't be there:

```
{
    return { success: false, message: 'error deleting user 2.'};
}
```

So I deleted it, saved the file, closed node, and run it again. However, the api endpoint that calls that function keeps returning { success: false, message: 'error deleting user 2.'}. I've made sure that this string of JSON is not present in any other place of my codebase, there is no code that can be ran that produces this result, yet it keeps being executed. What is happening? Why is old removed code being executed, is there any kind of caching I'm not aware of that survives resetting node?

Comment: If you restart node app then changes should be applied. Are you using deployment or run localy? Are you sure you save that changes? Are you sure you did restart app?

Comment: @VladimirG. I'm running it locally, changes are saved for sure (I closed the editor and opened the file with another app to check) and I'm sure the app was restarted since I'm using nodemon (which resets node on save) and I closed the terminal to open a new one just in case.